# Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: rust, build-bpf, build-sbf

##### Problem

I have a problem on build Rust Solana contract on processor M1. I used a simple example hello world.

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::AccountInfo, entrypoint, entrypoint::ProgramResult, msg, pubkey::Pubkey,
};

// declare and export the program's entrypoint
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

// program entrypoint's implementation
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    // log a message to the blockchain
    msg!("Hello, world!");

    // gracefully exit the program
    Ok(())
}
```

Error message:

```
Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf
cargo-build-bpf child: /Users/ivan/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --arch bpf
error: command failed: 'cargo': Bad CPU type in executable (os error 86)
```

I found a solution, to download rosetta, but is there a way to build an app with `cargo build-bpf` without rosetta?

Comment: Weird i am using Monterey and i can build. Which Solana cli version are you using? Edit: Oh looks like i also have rosetta installed. So probably its required

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got the wrong version of the tool suite. If you look at a release page like https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/releases/tag/v1.16.8 you'll see that the `aarch64` binaries are provided, so be sure to download those!

I don't use a Mac, but if you run `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.16.8/install)"`, that should fetch the correct binaries.

Or of course, you can build the tools yourself from master.